# Scala : Converting object having UUID field to Json returns blank

Tags: json, scala, uuid

Here is my case class that i want to convert to Json

```
case class Cart(cart_id :UUID, cart_entries :Map[String,CartEntry]){
}
```

I am using net.liftweb.json._

```
implicit val formats = UUID
val json = write(cart) //cart is Cart object with values for both attributes cart_id = 68eb787f-746c-4320-9ef4-8b5c7f0d7e21
println(json)
```

the json returns somthing like :

```
{"cart_id":{},"cart_entries":[{"_1":"ABC","_2":{"sku_id":"ABC","quantity":12,"price":{"bigDecimal":{},"mc":{}}}}]}
```

notice the value for cart_id is blank {} , I expect something like :

```
{"cart_id":{68eb787f-746c-4320-9ef4-8b5c7f0d7e21},"cart_entries":[{"_1":"ABC","_2":{"sku_id":"ABC","quantity":12,"price":{"bigDecimal":{},"mc":{}}}}]}
```

I have used other api's like fasterxml all return "" for UUID .
How do i fix this  ?

Comment: I assume you want `{"cart_id":"68eb787f-746c-4320-9ef4-8b5c7f0d7e21", ...`, i.e. the UUID is enclosed in quotation marks `""` rather than `{}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your `Cart` is a case class composed of types for which lift-json provides serializers, the `UUID` class probably isn't (I assume you use `java.util.UUID`). Therefore you need to [write your own serializer & deserializer](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json#serializing-non-supported-types), with something like this (untested):

```
     def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
       case x: UUID => JString(x.toString)
     }
```

Comment: I created the custom serializer as :

import java.util.UUID

import net.liftweb.json._

class UUIDserializer extends Serializer[UUID] {
  private val UUIDClass = classOf[UUID]

  def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), UUID] = {
    case (TypeInfo(UUIDClass, _), json) => json match {
      case _ => UUID.randomUUID() //TODO
    }
  }

  def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case x: UUID => JString(x.toString)
  }
}

But this isn't getting called  while serialising the cart class's UUID variable

Comment: My bad , i forgot to add the 
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new UUIDserializer , its working fine , thanks @m01